# Hole in hose on Dishwasher drain kit

Tags: dishwasher

As in attached picture the hose on the drain punmp of my GE dishwasher seems to have developed a hole and is leaks when the dishwasher runs.

I contacted GE for a solution but not much luck.

Can anyone suggest any Waterproof sealant that might help in this situation.
Any alternate fixes ?

[image]

[image: Hole]

Thank you

Comment: You could  search the model number and see if there are replacement parts available. There are many parts suppliers online for appliances.

Comment: Do you have the model number of the washer? Can you pull the hose off the impeller housing?

Comment: I'm going to suggest that patching this is NOT the right approach.  Getting things to stick to materials like this especially in the presence of hot soapy water is impossible.  Get a replacement part.  Yes, you will likely need to buy the complete assembly.

Comment: Your first picture looks like it came from an online parts supplier. (I found the same one.) The whole pump is $29 US. Unless you’re somewhere else where it’s unavailable, there is no better option.

Comment: @JACK The whole unit is one piece per my understanding. GE does not have a the part and suggested I call local distributors. So will need to look.

Comment: what is leaking? ... the rubber part seems to have a round hole in its side

Comment: @jsotola, it is the black rubber hose that is leaking

Answer (score 1):

I would not give up repairing it.

The pump has a plastic shoulder that the rubber part mounts into.  Take some sandpaper and rough this area up.  Then go to the auto parts store and buy a foot of coolant hose that has an ID slightly larger than the shoulder and will slip over it and buy a hose clamp.  Also buy a tube of silicone high temp RTV get the stuff the stays soft.

Cover the rubber host with a liberal amount of the RTV and then slide the coolant hose over that so that the space between hoses is filled with the RTV.  The other end should be exposed just enough for space for it's hose clamp.  Clamp down the coolant hose on the pump side.  Jam in as much RTV as you can without collapsing the inner hose.  If the RTV tube has a plastic nozzle you can jam this down between hoses and squirt more in.

Reconnect everything and clamp it down around the other side (which I assume connects to the tub)  Let it cure and see if it holds.

Comment: thanks @ted-mittelstaedt will look into this